# How to use commands like DROP TABLE etc. within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I have written a script which is intended to be scheduled to run overnight to copy yesterday's tables, drop yesterday's tables, create new tables, then compare changes. This is working fine as a scheduled task, but I am really struggling to find a way of allowing the users to execute it on the fly for testing purposes.

What I really want to do is to pack it all into a stored procedure, as I have an eForm tool which will easily allow the user (very non-technical) to be able to execute the procedure with a click.

Here is an example of the start of the script. Can anyone help me shoehorn this into a stored procedure as it clearly won't accept commands like DROP TABLE as standard.

Thanks.

```
DROP TABLE SQL2005TEST.ABSENCEFULLDATADIFF_YESTERDAY;
DROP TABLE SQL2005TEST.ABSENCELATESTSTART_YESTERDAY;
DROP TABLE SQL2005TEST.ABSENCELATESTEND_YESTERDAY;

CREATE TABLE SQL2005TEST.ABSENCEFULLDATADIFF_YESTERDAY
 AS SELECT * FROM SQL2005TEST.ABSENCEFULLDATADIFF;

CREATE TABLE SQL2005TEST.ABSENCELATESTSTART_YESTERDAY
 AS SELECT * FROM SQL2005TEST.ABSENCELATESTSTART;

CREATE TABLE SQL2005TEST.ABSENCELATESTEND_YESTERDAY
 AS SELECT * FROM SQL2005TEST.ABSENCELATESTEND;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_name AS
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE SQL2005TEST.ABSENCEFULLDATADIFF_YESTERDAY';
.....
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE SQL2005TEST.ABSENCELATESTEND_YESTERDAY
                       AS SELECT * FROM SQL2005TEST.ABSENCELATESTEND';
....
....
EXCEPTION
  ....
  ....
END;
```

The `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement executes a dynamic SQL statement or anonymous PL/SQL block, within a PL/SQL block, or Stored Procedure, or Package. This is more specifically used if you need to run DDL statements like `DROP`, `CREATE TABLE` etc. You cannot execute DDL commands from PL/SQL as DML statements, so the only way is dynamic SQL. More info [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems017.htm).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I actually tried this earlier and couldn't get it to work.  However, with renewed confidence following your answer I just tried again and this time it's working.  Don't know what went wrong ealier.  Probably half-heartedness due to not knowing what I was doing.

Comment: Nothing too funky here just a bunch of Dynamic SQLs! :)