# How can I execute DDL command CREATE or ALTER or DROP in oracle apex process?

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to kill session from oracle apex form ,
how can I execute kill session command ,

I tried the following :

1- created an interactive report with form using this SELECT statement

```
select sid , serial# , blocking_session from v$session;
```

2- In the form linked with this grid I select SID and SERIAL

3- I created process and used the code :

```
begin
alter system kill session ''' ||  :P90_SID || ',' || :P90_SERIAL_H  || ''';
 end;
```

but I got the error :

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following: ( begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query json_object json_array
```

how to solve this error and execute kill session ?

update :

I am using database link apex installed on 19c database and production database run on 10g database , the issue for this error was when I select the sessions i select using database link

```
select sid , serial# , blocking_session from v$session@kaash;
```

but when I run the command its try to kill the session on the current database and show the error ORA:00030 User session ID does not exist.
how can I add the database link to kill session command @kaash ?

and thank you for professional ansewrs .

Comment: ddl commands cannot be executed directly in pl/sql. Use ```EXECUTE IMMEDIATE```

Comment: @KoenLostrie how to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE can you post the command please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use commands like DROP TABLE etc. within a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801533/how-to-use-commands-like-drop-table-etc-within-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: @KoenLostrie how to pass SID and serial value and how to call procedure in apex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, it is easier to compose statement to be executed; doing that, it is simple to verify whether it looks OK or not. Then execute it.

I'd create a **button** on form page which runs a process that looks like this:

```
declare
  l_str varchar2(200);
begin
  l_str := 'alter system kill session ' || chr(39) || :P90_SID || ', '|| :P90_SERIAL_H || chr(39);
  execute immediate l_str;
end;
```

Of course, user (who pushes that button) has to have appropriate privileges. Not everyone is allowed to alter system.

Comment: I tried the code but when click kill session button it show error ORA-00030 : user session ID does not exist with all sessions  , thank you

Comment: Put L_STR into some page item which is displayed on the screen; doing so, you'd be able to see which command you're trying to execute. When you verify that it is OK, open Apex' SQL Workshop and try to execute that ALTER SYSTEM there and see what happens.

Comment: I created new page item P90_L_STR how to put L_STR into it ? sorry I am still new to apex , thank you :)

Comment: In process, just say `:P90_L_STR := l_str;`. Comment EXECUTE IMMEDIATE so that it wouldn't execute (because you said it doesn't work anyway).

Comment: I did this but its not show the command in the page item  declare
  l_str varchar2(200);
begin
  l_str := 'alter system kill session ' || chr(39) || :P90_SID || ', '|| :P90_SERIAL_H || chr(39);
  :P90_L_STR := l_str;
end;

Comment: Did you create **button** which **submits** the page? If so, then that process *should* run and populate P90_L_STR item.

Comment: last point please can i connect to remote database after begin then kill the session example connect  system/system@kaash      then l_str := 'alter system kill session ....'

Comment: No, that won't work. CONNECT command works from SQL*Plus. Apex' procedures are **PL/SQL** which run in database. Once you establish connection, you can't change it.

Answer (score 2):

In apex, the API `APEX_STRING` can be used to avoid multiple concatenations and make code a bit more readable. This does the same as @Littlefoots' answer.

```
DECLARE
  l_statement VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
  l_statement := q'!ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION '%0,%1'!';
  l_statement := apex_string.format(l_statement, :P90_SID, :P90_SERIAL_H);
  apex_debug.info(
    p_message => q'#Ziad debug: Statement: %0#',
    p0        => l_statement);

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_statement;
END;
```

This code can be execute as part of a page process after page submit or as part of a dynamic action, depending on the flow of your page.

-- update --

one way of debugging the code is the apex API `APEX_DEBUG`. Run the page in debug mode, check the debug logs and look for the string "Ziad debug".

Comment: I tried the code but when click kill session button it show error ORA-00030 : user session ID does not exist with all sessions also can you try it in your side , thank you

Comment: I don't have access to an environment where I'm able to kill sessions from within an apex application. I suggest you try to kill a session first from within the sql workshop. Once you have that working move it to an apex page.